# How to proceed with ghost bookings on booking.com?

Tags: booking.com

This question may be out of bounds in this forum. I would be happy with a redirect to a different forum.

I've used Booking.com several times for booking stays and hotels. But recently I received several unsolicited emails via booking.com in connection to a booking made there at a place I never checked for a person I do not know.

I received a booking confirmation, followed by a no show notice, followed by a cancellation email by the property.

At first I rejected them as some sort of spammy mails. Later when I logged onto Booking.com I found the same place listed on my profile.

This was alarming to me. My login credentials are very secure and I make it a point to not store financial data on online platforms.

That means somehow someone else got hold of my login credentials and used it on the website.

I changed the password and set up 2FA.

I also reached out to the twitter handle for Booking.com, but so for they have been non-responsive.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Do not only use twitter, use the support/report a problem option to make them aware. Document which booking are real and which are "fake".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a support question and should really go directly to Booking.com